# Bypass Cakephp operation

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp

In CakePHP, I wish to run a basic php file (native, not Cake) without running through a controller and a view. The file does output to the screen.

I tried putting the file in the /app/webroot folder but I get an error that the controller could not be found.

I wrapped this in a controller and view that simply include the desired file, but I probably missed something in Cake 101 - there gotta be a better way...

Thanks,

Dorian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the file in `app/webroot/` is correct.

However, as you get a "controller not found" error I guess you called it in the wrong way. You have to provide the file extension when requesting files in `app/webroot/`, i.e. you have to use http://example.com/foo.php instead of http://example.com/foo.

Comment: if you dont want to mess up your webroot you could also use a random folder and do something like this http://dogmatic69.com/blog/development/7-using-other-apps-with-cakephp-htaccess-config